# Recursive hard link

Tags: powershell, cp, hardlink

With Unix `cp` you can use the `--link` option. When used with a folder, it will
[hard link](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) the files involved instead of
copying, example

```
cp --recursive --link foo bar
```

This can be ideal in certain situations because it is faster than regular
copying. Can anything like this be done with PowerShell?

Answer (score 3):

PowerShell doesn't have support for Symbolic/Hard Links currently. There are improvements on this front coming in PowerShell 5.0. The latest preview (September 2014) includes some of this functionality. You may want to peruse the [release notes (docx)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/D/B/EDB86AD9-4D26-4C33-A8B2-82BE161682E2/Windows%20Management%20Framework%205.0%20Experimental%20Release%20July%202014%20Release%20Notes.docx):

> To support symbolic links, *-Item and a few related cmdlets have been extended. Now you can create symbolic links in a single, simple line with New-Item.

An example:

```
New-Item -ItemType HardLink -Path C:\Temp -Name MyHardLinkFile.txt -Value $pshome\profile.ps1
```

There isn't an example for `Copy-Item`, but I assume it would be simple to use this with a recursive `Get-ChildItem` and pipe the results to `New-Item`, but you would have to try it yourself.

In the meantime, the [PowerShell Community Extensions](https://pscx.codeplex.com/) project has a `New-Hardlink` cmdlet. From the looks of it, you would have to do as I described above and pipe the results of Get-ChildItem into this cmdlet to create a hardlink for each file.